# Can't access website hosted by raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache2

I am trying to see a website hosted on my raspberry pi with apache2, but when I enter 'locahost' or '127.0.0.1' in my browser, it says :

```
This site can not be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you running the web browser on the RPi, as well as the server? The address 127.0.0.1 only works for location connections. If the browser is on the Pi, check that the webserver is actually running; use `netstat` to check that it is actually listening on port 80

Comment: No the browser is running on an other computer on the same network

Comment: Then the IP number is wrong. You need to give the IP number of the Pi. Your asking your web browser to connect to its own host.

Comment: How do I get its correct IP then?

Comment: if it's connected via cable (ethernet): `ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr"` display the exposed ip address

Comment: And if its connect by wifi?

Comment: Never mind I have found out how, thanks for your help

Comment: What did you do? I'm having a similar issue.